# Java Unzip - no Exception but result is empty

Tags: java, stream, unzip, zip

i'm using the following code from the web

```
File dir = new File(dest.getAbsolutePath(), archiveName);
    // create output directory if it doesn't exist
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdirs();
    }
    System.err.println(pArchivePath);
ZipFile zipFile = null;
    try {
        zipFile = new ZipFile(pArchivePath);
        Enumeration<?> enu = zipFile.entries();
        while (enu.hasMoreElements()) {
            ZipEntry zipEntry = (ZipEntry) enu.nextElement();

            String name = zipEntry.getName();
            long size = zipEntry.getSize();
            long compressedSize = zipEntry.getCompressedSize();
            System.out.printf("name: %-20s | size: %6d | compressed size: %6d\n", 
                    name, size, compressedSize);

            File file = new File(name);
            if (name.endsWith("/")) {
                System.err.println("make dir " + name);
                file.mkdirs();
                continue;
            }

            File parent = file.getParentFile();
            if (parent != null) {
                parent.mkdirs();
            }

            InputStream is = zipFile.getInputStream(zipEntry);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = is.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
                fos.write(bytes, 0, length);
            }
            is.close();
            fos.close();

        }
        zipFile.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (zipFile != null) {
            try {
                zipFile.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

to unzip an archive. It's packed with 7zip or Winrar as an .zip archive but renamed to .qtz (but i don't thing this causes the problem..)
So if i run the code to unzip my archive everything works fine: i get the output on sysout/err listing all files and also no exception occurs, but if i look in the destination directory ... it's empty - just the root folder exists.

I also used

```
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String.format("unzip %s -d %s", pArchivePath, dest.getPath()));
```

but I can't use this anymore 'cause a new process is started and I'm continuing working on the archive right after the unzip process in the java code.

Well the question is.. why doesn't this peace of code work? There a lot of similar examples but none of them worked for me.

br, Philipp

EDIT: The following solved my Problem

```
File file = new File(dir.getParent(), name);
```

So i didn't set the right parent path for this file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below fragment in your code:

```
       File parent = file.getParentFile();
        if (parent != null) {
            parent.mkdirs();
        }
```

where does this create the parent directories? Because I tried your code and it's not creating in the destination directory but rather in my Eclipse's project directory. Looking at your code, the destination directory is nowhere used, right?

The code actually extracts the contents of the zip file but not where I expected it.

Comment: Yeah this was a good hint. The problem was that 'parent' took the parent path of 'file'. So i've just initialize 'file' with new File(dir.getParent(), name); and now it works for me.

Comment: Cool. Can you please mark the question as answered?

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking because I don't see you doing something like this:

```
ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipPath+ "Zip.zip"));
out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("Results.csv"));
```

I am still working on it but I think that the problem because that makes the file inside of the zip

Also you should probably use the ZipOutputStream to write; like

```
out.write(bytes, 0, length);
```